# Output HTML in PHP with if/else?

Tags: php, html

I want to output html under a certain condition.  How do I work PHP into this?
The following code does not work...

```
    <h2>Hello, 

        <?php
          session_start(); 
          if (isset($_SESSION['valid_user'])){ 
            //user is actually logged in, so display their name in top right corner
            echo $_SESSION['valid_user'];
          } else{
            echo " Guest ";
          }

          ?>
      </h2>
```

It only outputs "Hello," .

EDIT: THANK YOU RELENTLESS for pointing out the most fundamental part...

Comment: What happens? Is it possible 'valid_user' exists but is empty?

Comment: try storing the session in a variable such as `$User` and then echo it

Comment: It doesn't output anything...

Comment: try `var_dump($_SESSION['valid_user'])` and post the result

Comment: @user3476554 Storing it in a variable won't do anything.  There's nothing obvious wrong with your code - have you checked to see if `$_SESSION['valid_user']` is an empty string?  In that case, `isset($_SESSION['valid_user'])` will return true and you will just see "Hello,".

Comment: Don't think its a problem with the session arrray, because if nothing is in there, it should go to the else statement.

Comment: @user3476554 That's what we're saying: if `$_SESSION['valid_user']` is set *to an empty string*, it *won't* go to the else.

Comment: Attempt search on the www

Comment: Again... try `var_dump($_SESSION['valid_user'])` and post the result

Comment: var dump isn't working inside my php tag....nothing displays at all...

Comment: At the VERY top of the script, before anything else, do this: `<?php
session_start(); var_dump($_SESSION['valid_user']); ?>`

Comment: Again nothing is outputting...I have bootstrap CSS linked as well..let me disable that and see if i see anything.

Comment: This file is saved as a .php not .html file, correct?

Comment: bootstrap shouldn't have any effect on this...

Comment: great, thats the problem...im working in a index.html file without noticing it....duhh.... sorry, group project here...

Answer (score 4):

You *cannot* `session_start();` after output. Place this in `<?php ?>` at the very top of the file (before any other output).

In its current form, your code probably stops executing after triggering the error at this point, never getting to the `if( isset() )`.

Comment: Ah, good catch.  This is likely OP's issue.  OP, always be sure to check your error logs (and turn display_errors on when you're developing).  If this is the case, look at the source - you'll notice the closing `</h2>` isn't there either.

Comment: Did that..No dice.. I'm wondering if CSS is hiding this somewhere... My echo statement should take on the properties of <h2> in CSS correct?, since they are in the <h2> </h2> tags..

Comment: Yes, correct. It will be a part of the `<h2>` tag. If you look in the page's source code, is there a closing `</h2>`? Probably the PHP is not getting executed fully. If you see the closing `</h2>`, then are you sure you've set a name to the variable? Like, try: `echo "[[" . $_SESSION['valid_user'] . "]]";` and see if you see the brackets, e.g. `"Welcome, [[]]"`. If so, everything is working correctly *except* at the place in your code where you define `$_SESSION['valid_user'] = ...`

Comment: the closing </h2> tag is at the bottom.. after the closing ?>PHP tag.. is no one seeing that in the OP?

Comment: Not your source code, I mean if you "View Source" in the outputted page in your browser window...

Comment: No, they're talking about in the rendered page when you load it in a web browser. If the PHP is bombing out because of the `session_start()` call, then it'll stop sending output to the browser when it hits there, then you won't see the closing `</h2>` tag.

Comment: He saved the file as a .html file... see comments above.